# Getting the rightmost point of gameobject

Tags: unity, pixel

How do i determin the point on a gameobject that is most to the right (highest x value).

Comment: There is no direct conversion, unless you are developing a 2D game with a fixed camera. Can you edit your answer, including more information as defined in the help center: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Take a look at Orthello and how they set up the camera. One unit in Unity is equal to one pixel in their case.

Comment: Sorry guys. This was a bad question i edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bad question, i admit it. 
But for who ever that comes along later i solved the 2nd quesiton like this.

```
var bounds = gameObject.renderer.bounds.max.x;
```